# How to set the module name or path used in require() calls of a module in browserify?

Tags: browserify, tsify

I am using browserify to move a reusable typescript module into the browser using gulp.

```
gulp.task("default", function(){
return browserify({
                        basedir: '.',
                        debug: true,
                        require: ['./src/common/common.ts'],
                        fullPaths: false,
                        cache: {},
                        packageCache: {}
                    }).plugin(tsify)
    .bundle()
    .pipe(source('common.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest("dist"));
});
```

To my surprise I need to include the resulting common.js file via

```
require("c:\\Users\\Luz\\Desktop\\tstest\\client\\src\\common\\common.ts");
```

In typescript or in builds using UMD + require JS I require files using relative paths without problems with exactly the same code. In the moment I add browserify I get absolute paths. I tried compiling typescript myself and use browserify without tsify but it always demands an absolute path to include it. All other modules that require common.js will fail to find it. How can I fix this?

Edit: Example how it looks like in the html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <script src="common.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            console.log("script started");

            //works
            var test = require("c:\\Users\\Luz\\Desktop\\tstest\\client\\src\\common\\common.ts");
            test.printCommon();

            //fails (all other modules will try to find it at this path)
            var test2 = require("../common/common");
            test2.printCommon();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

While I couldn't find the root of the problem I found a solution that works:

```
var brofy = browserify({
                        basedir: '.',
                        debug: true
                    });
    brofy.plugin(tsify);
    brofy.require("./src/common/common.ts", { expose: "../common/common" });
    brofy.bundle()
    .pipe(source('common.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest("dist"));
```

The property expose will make sure that require("../common/common") leads to the correct module avoiding any absolute paths and allowing me to use the same paths I use in typescript.

Other bundles can reference the bundle using "brofy.external("../common/common");" to tell browserify to not include it in their own bundle and rather use require to find it.

Edit: Still hoping someone comes up with a better solution.