# Browserify's custom dependency name is not working

Tags: node.js, browserify

I am trying to get browserify's custom dependency name working with memory streams. The reason I am using a memory stream is because this code is destined to run inside an AWS Lambda that will be receiving multiple "files" as inputs and will not be available to the lambda via the file system.

According to the documentation at https://github.com/substack/node-browserify, it seems like this should be possible:

> b.require(file, opts)
>
> file can also be a stream, but you should also use opts.basedir so that relative requires will be resolvable.
>
> Use the expose property of opts to specify a custom dependency name. require('./vendor/angular/angular.js', {expose: 'angular'}) enables require('angular')

Code:

```js
const browserify = require('browserify')
const path = require('path')
const File = require('vinyl')

const jsIndex = new File({
    file: path.resolve('index.js'),
    contents: new Buffer('var two = require("./two")')})
const jsTwo  = new File({
    file: path.resolve('two.js'),
    contents: new Buffer('console.log("Hello from two.js")')})

browserify({
        entries: [ jsIndex ],
        require: [ jsTwo ],
        basedir: path.resolve('.')
    })
    .bundle((err, res) => {
        if (err) console.log(err.message)
    })
    .pipe(process.stdout)
```

Error:

`Cannot find module './two' from '...'`

Edit:

Another individual has posted a similar issue on the node-browserify github page here: https://github.com/substack/node-browserify/issues/1622

Answer (score 1):

Browserify makes heavy use of the file system, as it implements its own module resolution that uses the same algorithm as Node's `require`. To get Browserify to bundle using in-memory source files, one solution would be to monkey patch the file system - in a manner similar to the [`mock-fs`](https://github.com/tschaub/mock-fs) module that's useful for testing.

However, you really only want to do this for the source files. Browserify uses its module resolution for other files that are included in the bundle and having to add those to the in-memory file system would be tedious. The patched file system functions should check for calls that involve in-memory source files, handle them accordingly and forward other calls to the original implementations. (`mock-fs` does something similar in that it detects file system calls that occur within `require` and forwards those calls to the original implementations.)

```
'use strict';

const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const toStream = require('string-to-stream');

// Create an object hash that contains the source file contents as strings,
// keyed using the resolved file names. The patched fs methods will look in
// this map for source files before falling back to the original
// implementations.

const files = {};
files[path.resolve('one.js')] =
    'console.log("Hello from one.js");' +
    'var two = require("./two");' +
    'exports.one = 1;';
files[path.resolve('two.js')] =
    'console.log("Hello from two.js");' +
    'exports.two = 2;';

// The three fs methods that need to be patched take a file name as the
// first parameter - so the patch mechanism is the same for all three.

function patch(method, replacement) {

    var original = fs[method];
    fs[method] = function (...args) {

        var name = path.resolve(args[0]);
        if (files[name]) {
            args[0] = name;
            return replacement.apply(null, args);
        } else {
            return original.apply(fs, args);
        }
    };
}

patch('createReadStream', function (name) {

    return toStream(files[name]);
});

patch('lstat', function (...args) {

    args[args.length - 1](null, {
        isDirectory: function () { return false; },
        isFile: function () { return true; },
        isSymbolicLink: function () { return false; }
    });
});

patch('stat', function (...args) {

    args[args.length - 1](null, {
        isDirectory: function () { return false; },
        isFile: function () { return true; }
    });
});

// With the fs module patched, browserify can be required and the bundle
// can be built.

const browserify = require('browserify');

browserify()
    .require(path.resolve('one.js'), { entry: true, expose: 'one' })
    .require(path.resolve('two.js'), { expose: 'two' })
    .bundle()
    .pipe(process.stdout);
```

#### `require` and `expose`

In your question, you mentioned `expose`. The `one.js` and `two.js` modules were bundled using `require`, so they can be required in the browser using the name specified in the `expose` options. If that's not what you want, you can just use `add` instead and they will be modules internal to the bundle.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>so-39397429</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="./bundle.js"></script>
    <script>
        // At this point, the bundle will have loaded and the entry
        // point(s) will have been executed. Exposed modules can be
        // required in scripts, like this:
        console.log(require('one'));
        console.log(require('two'));
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I spent some time looking into Browserify's `require` and `expose` options when investigating [this tsify question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38891391/6680611). The options facilitate the requiring of modules from outside the bundle, but I'm not at all sure they have any influence on requires between modules within the bundle (which is what you need). Also, their implementation is a little confusing - particularly [this part](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify/blob/13.1.0/index.js#L118-L128) in which the exposed name sometimes has a slash prepended.

#### Vinyl streams

In your question, you used `vinyl`. However, I wasn't able to use `vinyl` for the read streams. Although it does implement `pipe`, it's not an event emitter and doesn't seem to implement the `on`-based the pre-Streams 2 API - which is what Browserify expects from a `createReadStream` result.

Comment: while i was looking for a non-hacky solution, your monkey patch solution technically solves the problem. so i have awarded you the points, but i am keeping the answer open for other solutions.

Comment: i have also noticed that if i use your monkey patch technique, i do not need the `createReadStream` method, monkey patching the lstat and stat are enough to get browserify to work.

Comment: The patch to `createReadStream` **is** necessary. If it's working for you without it, it's reading the files from disk. I've added some notes to the answer regarding `require`/`expose` and why I think the monkey patch is the only viable option. However, it will be interesting to see whether or not an alternative solution is possible, as this one is not pretty.

Comment: I have created a gist where I have merged your monkey patching (with createReadStream omitted) with my code including the vinyl streams. This code produces the correct output. These files do not exist on the disk. https://gist.github.com/joelnet/801172fa765ef4a8f11f94d044604dd2

Comment: Yep, I see what you mean. That's a neater solution. I guess Browserify uses `pipe` for streams it receives via options and `on` for streams it receives via `createReadStream` calls.