# Browserify insert global variable

Tags: browserify

Despite there are a lot of relative questions, they do not answer how to resolve the following issue.

I have a nodejs file index.js.

```
var browserify = require('browserify');

var data = getSomeData();
browserify('entry.js').bundle();
```

I want so that `data`could be accessed in `entry.js`. I found browserify option `insertGlobalVars` but I could not find any proper documentation or examples. I tried `{insertGlobalVars: {myVar: someData}}` but it does not work.

I could not call `require('someData')` because my data is produced only when executing `index.js`.

**Update**:
Data is an array; key is a file name, value - file content (size is about 500b).

Comment: What sort of data? Is it convertible to JSON? And how large is it?

Comment: @cartant I updated the question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `insertGlobalVars` option takes an [object that contains functions](https://github.com/substack/insert-module-globals#insert-custom-globals) (called with `file` and `basedir` arguments). So you would have to specify your `insertGlobalVars` option like this:

```
var browserify = require('browserify');
var someData = getSomeData();

browserify('entry.js', {
    insertGlobalVars: {
        someData: function () { return JSON.stringify(someData); }
    }
})
.bundle()
.pipe(process.stdout);
```

Note that the data will only be included in the bundle if the `someData` global is actually used in the code. And each  module that uses the global will receive its own copy.

It would be possible to inject an additional module into the bundle, so that the data could be required (and the bundle would contain only a single copy of the data), but that would be more complicated due to the interaction between `module-deps` and the file system. For more information, you could have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39433893/6680611).

Comment: The answer is more than acceptable. But what I realy needed is the proper browserify documentation. If it existed, I had not asked this question. I tried to browse a source code, but it is too coupled and I did not understood anything.

Comment: Just a quick note on this answer: you just reference the someData global in the code. You don't need to do anything special. So in entry.js, you could add: console.log(someData) and it would run fine.